# Convert Excel "If" function to T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a table in a SQL Server database and Excel that looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4anT.png)

Using Excel to calculate the value of "D" in column "H" I have used the following formula:

```
=IF(G2="NULL",100,IF(A2="NULL",((E2-3-F2)/D2),IF(D2="NULL",((B2-3-C2)/A2),IF(((B2-3-C2)/A2)<((E2-3-F2)/D2),((B2-3-C2)/A2),((E2-3-F2)/D2)))))
```

The formula works fine and if I want to change the value 3 to 3.2 in the formula and update the values in Excel, I just change 3 to 3.2 to make it look like the formula below:

```
=IF(G2="NULL",100,IF(A2="NULL",((E2-3.2-F2)/D2),IF(D2="NULL",((B2-3.2-C2)/A2),IF(((B2-3.2-C2)/A2)<((E2-3.2-F2)/D2),((B2-3.2-C2)/A2),((E2-3.2-F2)/D2)))))
```

However I don't know how to convert this Excel formula to a SQL query and I would appreciate if anyone can help me in writing the correct SQL query statement based on the above formula. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? mysql <> sql server. And what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sean, I am using MS SQL Server 2008 and I have not tried anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL SERVER you can use [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) expression to evaluates a list of conditions and returns one of multiple possible result expressions.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN G2 IS NULL THEN 100 
    ELSE 
    CASE WHEN A2 IS NULL THEN (E2-3.2-F2)/D2 
        ELSE 
        CASE WHEN D2 IS NULL THEN (B2-3.2-C2)/A2
            ELSE
            CASE WHEN (B2-3.2-C2)/A2 < (E2-3.2-F2)/D2 THEN (B2-3.2-C2)/A2
                ELSE (E2-3.2-F2)/D2 
            END 
        END 
    END 
END AS Test
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks tezzo, this really helped me.